# How can I extract all email addresses from the 'text' field in PostgreSQL that contains XML with email addresses?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table named 'contacts'.
The table has a field of type 'text' named 'xml_data'.
The 'xml_data' field contains strings of XML data that includes 0-3 email addresses.
An example of the XML data is:

```
`<emailInfo><typedEmail><type>E-mail</type><value>user1@email1.com</value></typedEmail><datas><typedEmail><type/><value>user2@email2.com</value><active>true</active></typedEmail></datas></emailInfo>

`<emailInfo><typedEmail><type>Mail</type><value>user3@email3.com</value></typedEmail><datas><typedEmail><type>Mail</type><value>user4@email4.com</value></typedEmail></datas></emailInfo>`

`<emailInfo><typedEmail><type/><value>user5@email5.com</value></typedEmail><datas><typedEmail><type/><value>user6@email6.com</value><active>true</active></typedEmail></datas></emailInfo>`

`<emailInfo><typedEmail><type/><value>user7@email7.com</value></typedEmail><datas><typedEmail><type/><value>user8@email8.com</value><active>true</active></typedEmail></datas></emailInfo>`
```

Email addresses are always enclosed within  and  tags.
However, sometimes the XML string does not contain an email address and looks like this:

```
`<emailInfo><typedEmail><value/></typedEmail></emailInfo>`
```

I want to extract all email addresses from the 'xma_data' field for each record and return the results in a non-technical, human-readable format such as a comma-separated list of emails.
For example:

```
id; emails;
1; user1@email1.com,user2@email2.com;
2; user3@email3.com,user4@email4.com;
```

Can anyone suggest how to write a SQL query to achieve this? Thank you.

I tried expressions like:

```
select (xpath('//value/text()', xmlparse(content xml_data)))[1]::text AS email from contacts
```

or

```
select array_to_string(REGEXP_MATCHES(email_AB.xml_data, '<value>(.*?)</value>'), ',') AS email
```

The problem that these expressions extract the first email, but I need all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made your xpath a lot more complicated that it needed to be.

```
SELECT id
     , xpath('//value/text()', xml_data::xml) AS emails
  FROM contacts;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C22OLvMK)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the 'g' flag to match all:

```
REGEXP_MATCHES(email_AB.xml_data, '<value>(.*?)</value>', 'g')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same only first email :(